# Date field fails using .any and .anything

Tags: jestjs, snapshot-testing

I am writing Jest snapshot tests. I have a field that is a date string and it always fails the snapshot. I've tried testing:

```js
expect(reducer(initialModel, action)).toMatchSnapshot({
  startDate: expect.any(Date),
});
```

however, that fails. I've also tried `expect.anything()` and the snapshot fails on the date:

```
-   "startDate": "2023-12-18T23:23:16.731-07:00",
+   "startDate": Anything,
```

Why is this failing?

Comment: The `expect.any(Date)` matcher is used for Date objects, not date strings. Therefore, maybe Jest is failing to match the expected Date object with the actual date string. Try once `startDate: expect.any(String)`

Comment: @mandy8055 I did that as well. Same result. In any case, it doesn't explain why `.anything()` would fail.